# CSS not showing when deploying Angular application

Tags: angular, nginx, webdeploy

I followed this [tutorial](https://balramchavan.medium.com/deploy-angular-application-in-nginx-server-on-digitalocean-ubuntu-droplet-28380524811e) for deploying my Angular app on a Digital Ocean droplet running Debian 11 and nginx.

1. I ran the command `ng build`
2. and then copied the files inside `dist` directory to `/var/www/html`.

The problem is that even if inside the console CSS it's being downloaded correctly, style is not showing up at all.

This is the content of my `/var/www/html` directory:

[image: /var/www/html content]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i didn't show how i imported the styles because i followed the basic tailwind implementation with angular found in the official guide here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular

Comment: Again, you need to show your code and not expect us to assume. See [ask].